# Need Membership Chair to access CiviCRM Memberships, Treasurer to access Contributions. On Drupal

Tags: civicontribute, civimail, drupal, civimember, acl

In Drupal we have various roles set up for the Membership Chairperson, the Treasurer, and other committees.

We are trying to give access to these same functions through CiviCRM, not Drupal. Our Drupal developer is gone but the roles are already built and assigned.

So, using CiviCRM, we'd like *only* the membership chair to have access to all CiviCRM Memberships AND Mailings AND Events and *only* the treasurer to have access to Contributions AND Mailings AND Events.

So the roles are done in Drupal. How do we implement the same in CiviCRM so new committee chairs can go through the Civi interface instead of Drupal's? I'm getting confused understanding ACLs.

Using CiviCRM 5.44.0 on Drupal 8/9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal permissions/roles are what control what someone sees/does in the backend of civicrm. so you may just need to run your eye down the many, many rows of CiviCRM Permissions for those Roles.

Comment: Oh, okay. Now I just need to set the permissions correctly. Thanks!